# How to call an indicator which has a space character in its title?

Tags: pine-script

I'm writing a strategy that calls an indicator which has a space character in its name ("MarketCypher B").  What is the correct syntax for calling this indicator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try spell it with an "i" instead of "y"?
It also has a padlock, pay stuff.

Comment: You're right that it's an i not a y, but that doesn't solve my problem of the space character.

Comment: Also, I've paid for the indicator so it is unlocked for me.  I can use it on my charts.  I just don't know how to call it in pine editor.